# How to pull a row whose date value is null

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, groovy, hibernate-criteria

I have the following Criteria in hibernate and I would like to know how to handle when date column is null. I want to pull the row even if the date column has null value.

For example the MySQL query is:

```
Select * from myTable where date is null;
```

I used following query to pull the result.

```
 def query1 = myTable.createCriteria().list {
       if(m1?.startDate)
           eq('startDate', m1?.startDate)
       else
          IsNull('startDate')
       if(m1?.endDate)
           eq('endDate', m1?.endDate)
       else
           IsNull('endDate')
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Except from suspecting that `IsNull` is not correct here (it should be `isNull`) you have not really stated what problem you are facing.

Comment: The problem here is, even if I am checking isNull property in the date column, the query is not pulling the row that has null in date.

Comment: If your query has satartDate and endDate is it not necessary to write "and/or"? I seem like "Select * from myTable where startDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'/is null or/and endDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd'/is null". (I don't know Criteria so it may be an inappropriate comment.)

Comment: You can make use of Specification here

Comment: add sql query logging and see how your queries look like